# How can I move the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making songs player and want to know how to move from one song `trench01` to second song `trench02` etc with arrays. Here's the code I made but not seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var playthis = new Audio();
    var trench01 = 'songs/example1.m4a';
    var trench02 = 'songs/example2.m4a';
    playthis.src = [trench01,trench02];
    $('.play').click(function(){
        playthis.play();
        $('.pause').removeClass('notActiveButton');
        $(this).addClass('notActiveButton');
    });
    $('.pause').click(function(){
        playthis.pause();
        $('.play').removeClass('notActiveButton');
        $(this).addClass('notActiveButton');
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="pause"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
<button class="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
```

Comment: You have used variables `trench01` and `trench02` before defining them.   `playthis.src` should be set after defining both variables.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Fixed, But still not working...

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you using devtools?  What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I get "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException" on "playthis.play();" this line

Comment: try to change the line `playthis.play();` to `playthis.play().catch(console.error);` and tell us what the console contains.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `DOMException
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ index.html:116 //line 116 is playthis.play() line
dispatch @ jquery.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4878`

Comment: You cannot assign an array to `Audio.src`. You have to assign a single url.

Comment: @MofX Can you recommend me any other ways to do my task ?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Really? Do you have a link to the reference? I looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio and it says "url"